# Запустить системный сервис из крона (centos6)

Tags: bash, cron, service, centos6

Помогите разобраться в чём дело,
есть скрипт (torstop.bash)

```
#!/bin/bash

service tor stop
```

при запуске скрипта по ssh всё отрабатывает корректно, tor останавливается.

команда:

> /bin/bash /home/Backup/torstop.bash

но эта же команда в кроне не дает никакого результата, сервис не останавливается(

В логах крона (/var/log/cron), вроде как всё норм

> CROND[12303]: (root) CMD (/bin/bash /home/Backup/torstop.bash
>    >/dev/null 2>&1)

Другие скрипты bash (работа с файлами, удаление файлов) работают нормально.

В чём может быть дело?

Comment: Попробуйте вывод скрипта направить не в /dev/null 2>&1, а куда-нибудь в файл. Может что полезное скажет.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо Oxyd за подсказку!

перенаправил ошибки в файл, дописав "service tor stop 2>/home/cron_log",

увидел "service: command not found",

в терминале набрал "which service", узнал путь до service "/sbin/service",

теперь команда "/sbin/service tor stop", отрабатывает из крона!